# Placing a dot on an image - onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A user will be able to click on 3 points on an image, and i want to display a BLACK dot at those points. Then i will save these values in my database, and regenerate the image with those 3 points later on.

This is a 2 part question:

1.) In my code, i am not able to detect the onClick event when the image is clicked. Can someone look into this. Here's my code. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/95vczfve/1/)

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('body').click(function (ev) {
          alert("d");
          mouseX = ev.pageX;
          mouseY = ev.pageY
          alert(mouseX + ' ' + mouseY);
          var color = '#000000';
          var size = '1px';
          $("body").append(
          $('<div></div>')
              .css('position', 'absolute')
              .css('top', mouseY + 'px')
              .css('left', mouseX + 'px')
              .css('width', size)
              .css('height', size)
              .css('background-color', color));
      });
  });
```

HTML

```
<body background="http://www.craigjoneswildlifephotography.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/CMJ57311.jpg">

</body>
```

2.) Say that i have the X and Y coordinates of the points, and how can i regenerate the image with those points ?

Comment: "_how can i regenerate the image_". Do you really want to generate an image, or just recreate those black divs on top?

Comment: Why are you chaining `css()` instead of using `css({ top: , left: })` - its cleaner and performs better http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/95vczfve/7/

Comment: Just an FYI, I just made on more update to my answer and to the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/62hnurzd/) in it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `document` instead of `body` (your `body` element has a calculated height of 0, but document is always the full size of the window):

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/95vczfve/5/

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).click(function (ev) {
          mouseX = ev.pageX;
          mouseY = ev.pageY
          console.log(mouseX + ' ' + mouseY);
          var color = '#000000';
          var size = '1px';
          $("body").append(
          $('<div></div>')
              .css('position', 'absolute')
              .css('top', mouseY + 'px')
              .css('left', mouseX + 'px')
              .css('width', size)
              .css('height', size)
              .css('background-color', color));
      });
  });
```

As a side note: Your original JSFiddle is also a great example of why you should not connect delegated events to `body` instead of `document`. The `body` element can be styled out of existence (also `document` exists before the DOM is even loaded) :)

Or, as Brian provided, a reduced version http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/95vczfve/7/:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $(document).click(function (ev) {        
        $("body").append(            
            $('<div></div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: ev.pageY + 'px',
                left: ev.pageX + 'px',
                width: '10px',
                height: '10px',
                background: '#000000'
            })              
        );               
    });

});
```

And Brian's final update with limit of 3 dots: http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/95vczfve/8/

Comment: Only prob I see tho, with 0 body height, all the divs are going to the same place

Comment: Here is the non chained css if you want to add it to your answer http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/95vczfve/7/

Comment: I liked the click on document better because it makes more sense. Oh well, here is a version including the 3 limit http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/95vczfve/8/

Comment: how could I append a circle rather than a rec?

Answer (score 5):

Your body has 0 height because it has 0 content.

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; }
```

Or try adding some content.

## jsFiddle

---

On a side tip, a lot of things about your jQuery can be made cleaner/easier:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //  here I asign the event dynamically, not needed for 'body' as such tag should always be present,
    //  but something you should look into
    //  see also: http://api.jquery.com/on/
    $(document).on('click', 'body', function(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY
        //  simply press F12 to look at your browsers console and see the results
        console.log('Mouse Position:\t' + mouseX + '|' + mouseY);
        //  no need in JS to write var for every variable declartion,
        //  just seperate with a comma
        var color = '#000000',
            size = '5px';   //  changed size to 5px from 1 just to make it easier to see what's going on for you
        //  No need to use $("body") since this event takes place on the body tag
        //  $(this), in an event, always equals the selector the event is tied to
        $(this).append(
            //  making an element with jquery is simple
            //  no need to insert whole tag, all you need is tag name and a closer
            //  like so
            $('<div />')
                //  easily tie all css together
                .css({
                    //  also, in jquery CSS, any css variable with a '-' 
                    //  can be renamed when assigning
                    //  simply remove the '-' and capitilize the first letter of the second word
                    //  like so, here in 'background-color'
                    backgroundColor: color,
                    height: size,
                    left: mouseX + 'px',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: mouseY + 'px',
                    width: size
                })
        );
    })
});
```

Comment: What do yo mean.Can  you show me this in JSfiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding part 2 of your question, my first thought is to include query params in the image URL, so that instead of `http://www.example.com/thingies/someimage.jpg` you get something like `http://www.example.com/thingies/someimage.jpg?x0=10&y0=25&x1=30&y1=5`.  From there you would simply check if that string has query params with names matching what you're looking for (`x0`, `y0`, `x1`, etc...) and place points according to those.

Alternatively, you could also store the parameters in the URL for that web page, but that might lead to noisy URLs depending on what you're doing.

This depends on the server storing the coordinates, though.

My second thought is [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage), would store the points with the client, but that means that the points are not necessarily sent to the server, and are being read only from the client's browser.  It also depends on the browser supporting that, and allowing that.  Of course, since 3 coordinates is a rather small set of data, it could be stored in a browser cookie.