# Trying to place a dot onto an image that rotates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an effect where an image is able to rotate and I can mark it with a dot.

I'm using HTML/CSS and either javascript or jquery, not picky as I'm trying to get a proof of concept first.  I have utilized the following stackoverflow post code to create the dot (and triangle):  [Placing a dot on an image - onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123410/placing-a-dot-on-an-image-onclick)

This works great prior to image rotation, but I am thinking that the coordinate system used to render the dot placement isn't taking into account the image movement.  If this is correct, the conversion is confusing me.
ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSSOM_View/Coordinate_systems

```js
var dotCounter = 0;

if ($('#compassRotatingWheel').show()) { // Only when the compass side is showing
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#compassRotatingWheel').click(function(ev) { // only mark within the div
      dotCounter++;
      var evDot = ev;
      var dotOrTriangle = e;
      var newLeft, newTop;
      switch (dotOrTriangle) {

        case 'dot':
          var getDivId = $(this).attr('id');
          console.log("ID: " + getDivId);
          //// This was an attempt to convert page coordinate system to cartesian coordinate system
          // when pageX > 248 
          //if (ev.pageX > 248) {
          //    newLeft = ((((ev.pageX - 248) * Math.cos((angle))) - (ev.pageY * Math.sin((angle))))).toString() + 'px'; // + (248 - 12)).toString() + 'px';
          //}
          //else {
          //    // when pageX < 248 
          //    newLeft = -((((248 - ev.pageX) * Math.cos((angle))) - (ev.pageY * Math.sin((angle))))).toString() + 'px'; // - (248 - 12)).toString() + 'px';
          //}

          //// When pageY > 292
          //if (ev.pageY > 292) {
          //    newTop = ((((ev.pageY - 292) * Math.cos((angle))) + (ev.pageX * Math.sin((angle))))).toString() + 'px'; // + (292 - 55)).toString() + 'px';
          //}
          //else {
          //    // When pageY < 292
          //    newTop = -((((292 - ev.pageY) * Math.cos((angle))) + (ev.pageX * Math.sin((angle))))).toString() + 'px'; // - (292 - 55)).toString() + 'px';
          //}


          // Set x,y to new x'y' (prime) location  ref: https://academo.org/demos/rotation-about-point/
          // Account for wheel center (248,292) and padding offset 12 & 55 
          newLeft = ((((ev.pageX - 248) * Math.cos((angle))) - (ev.pageY * Math.sin((angle)))) + (228 - 12)).toString() + 'px';
          newTop = ((((ev.pageY - 292) * Math.cos((angle))) + (ev.pageX * Math.sin((angle)))) + (292 - 55)).toString() + 'px';


          var dot = $("#compassRotatingWheel").append(
            $('<div id="dot' + dotCounter + '"></div>').css({
              position: 'absolute',
              left: newLeft, //((((ev.pageX - 252) * Math.cos((angle))) - (ev.pageY * Math.sin((angle)))) + (252 - 12)).toString() + 'px',
              top: newTop, //((((ev.pageY - 286) * Math.cos((angle))) + (ev.pageX * Math.sin((angle)))) + (286 - 55)).toString() + 'px',
              width: '5px',
              height: '5px',
              background: 'red',
              borderRadius: '50%'
            })
          );
          //parentDiv = this.Element.parentNode;
          //alert("This is the parent Div: " + parentDiv);
          //// LOTS of console.log debugging  :/
          showCoords(event);
          console.log("TOP: " + newTop);
          console.log("LEFT: " + newLeft);
          console.log("offset() " + dot.offset().toString());
          console.log("event.pageY: " + event.pageY);
          console.log('')
          console.log("Compare Dot Placement: \nX: " + event.pageX + "\nY: " + event.pageY + "\nAngle: " + angle);

          console.log("DOT 1 - Element Coordinates: \nleft: " + dot1.getBoundingClientRect().left + "\ntop: " + dot1.getBoundingClientRect().top);
          console.log("DOT 2 - Element Coordinates: \nleft: " + dot2.getBoundingClientRect().left + "\ntop: " + dot2.getBoundingClientRect().top);
          console.log("DOT 3 - Element Coordinates: \nleft: " + dot3.getBoundingClientRect().left + "\ntop: " + dot3.getBoundingClientRect().top);
          //console.log('Show Coordinates: ' + showCoords(event));
          //console.log("Current angle: " + (angle * 60) + "\nRadians: " + degreesToRadians(angle) + "\n PageX: " + ev.pageX + " \nPageY: " + ev.pageY + "\nTop: " +
          // (((ev.pageY - 55) * Math.cos(degreesToRadians(angle))) - (ev.pageX * Math.sin(degreesToRadians(angle)))) + "\nLeft: " +
          // (((ev.pageX - 12) * Math.cos(degreesToRadians(angle))) - (ev.pageY * Math.sin(degreesToRadians(angle)))));
          break;

        case 'triangle':


          // ref: https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/
          var triangle = $('#compassRotatingWheel').append(
            $('<div id="triangle' + dotCounter + '"></div>').css({
              position: 'relative',
              top: topAdjust + 'px',
              left: leftAdjust + 'px',
              width: '0px',
              height: '0px',
              borderLeft: '5px solid transparent',
              borderRight: '5px solid transparent',
              borderBottom: '10px solid limegreen'
            })
          );
          console.log("Compare Triangle Placement: \nX: " + event.pageX + "\nY: " + event.pageY + "\nAngle: " + angle);
          console.log('Show Coordinates: ' + showCoords(event));
          showCoords(event);

          break;
        default:
          console.log('error: need to choose correct case');
      }
      $('#compassRotatingWheel').unbind('click');
    });
  });

};


function rotateWheel() {
  innerWheel.mousemove(function(event) {

    var intX = event.pageX;
    var intY = event.pageY;
    if (lastY == intY) {
      if (intY > 292) {
        if (lastX < intX) {
          detectRotation('down');
        } else {
          detectRotation('up');
        }
      } else {
        if (lastX < intX) {
          detectRotation('up');
        } else {
          detectRotation('down');
        }
      }
    } else if (intX > 248) {
      if (lastY < intY) {
        detectRotation('up');
      } else {
        detectRotation('down');
      }
    } else {
      if (lastY < intY) {
        detectRotation('down');
      } else {
        detectRotation('up');
      }
    }
    lastY = intY;
    lastX = intX;
    blMouseMove = true;
    //Use to find center coordinates of wheel
    //console.log("Center x = " + intX.toFixed(2) + "\ny = " + intY.toFixed(2));
    selectedWheel = "innerWheel";
    //console.log("SelectedWheel = " + selectedWheel);
  });
}

function removeWheelRotation() {
  innerWheel.unbind("mousemove");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compass Face Side -->
<div id="compass">
  <div id="compassFaceSideFrame">
    <!-- layered images -->
    <div id="compassRotatingWheel" onclick="showCoords(event)" onmousedown="rotateWheel()" onmouseup="removeWheelRotation()">
      <!--<div .center-div id="insideCompass"></div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Compass wheel already rotates.  When I place a dot (or triangle) I'm hoping it will be where I actually click visually.  Need to match this with the actual {pageX,pageY} or I'm thinking a more accurate statement is the {x',y'} prime to allow the image to rotate.
ref: https://academo.org/demos/rotation-about-point/

Comment: The code in the question is missing at least a closing brace. Also note that as you call `$('#compassRotatingWheel').show()` outside of document.ready, the code will never be executed if you're running it in the `<head>`

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan.  I've deleted the extra closing brace.  Regarding the *.show(), I was trying to make this a conditional statement so dots only appear when this div is present.  Though I didn't provide all code, just a snippet, that is working as expected on my end.