# Get Coordinates (X,Y) of mouse click on image regardless of the device size

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a div with an background image on my website. I want to mark the place where a user clicked within this div with a red dot.
I use the following code which works partially (the dot gets placed):

 
JS:

```
    document.getElementById('auto').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var test = "a variable";
        var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    $(auto).append($('<div class="damage_dot">'+test+'</div>').css({
                        left: x + 'px',
                        top: y + 'px',
                        }));
```

Problem: 
the dot never appears at the place where I clicked. If I scroll or try to do the same on a mobile device, the differences between the point where I clicked and the dot are getting bigger.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you also share (part of) your html and css?

Comment: you can check this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123410/placing-a-dot-on-an-image-onclick/26123785

Comment: Thanks for the answers. However, this doesn't resolve my issue sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is what you are looking for:

https://plnkr.co/edit/vSdGW5TIGrGYpAdk?open=lib%2Fscript.js

`(function(funcName, baseObj) {
    document.getElementById('auto').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;
        $(auto).append($('<div class="damage_dot">a</div>').css({
            left: x + 'px',
            top: y + 'px',
        }));  // Add your code here
    });
})("docReady", window);`



`.damage_dot{
  color:red;
  position: absolute;
  height:2px;
  width: 2px;
}`